# Add own literal string as additional field in result of query - SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

How in SQLAlchemy ORM to make analogue of the following raw sql?

```
SELECT "http://example.com/page/"||table.pagename as pageUrl
```

Need get value from table, modify using ORM/Python (here just a string concatenation), and output in result of the SQLAlchemy query as additional field.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The SQLAlchemy string types have operator overloads that allow you to treat them like you'd treat Python strings in this case (string concatenation), but produce SQL expressions:

```
session.query(
        Table,
        ("http://example.com/page/" + Table.pagename).label("pageUrl"))
```

You can read more about SQLAlchemy's operator paradigm here: http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/tutorial.html#operators

Comment: Concatenation works only via '+' with strings type of args. But not via '%' or f-strings of Python 3.6.

Comment: Naturally, since there's no way to produce anything but a string from an f-string and overloading string formatting in general would be a bit pointless, if at all possible, since it'd be neigh impossible to support in a dialect agnostic way.

Answer (score 1):

This can make via `select`,  but there is almost no ORM:

```
from sqlalchemy.sql import select, text
q = select([text('"http://example.com/page/"||pagename as pageUrl')]).select_from(Table)
session.execute(q).fetchall()
```

Results will a list of objects in the `RowProxy` class.

For me seems that the solve via `session.query` (the answer above) is more convenient. It is short, and there results in `result` class that can be easy converting to dict.